# Does tmux support session initialization?

Tags: configuration, tmux

Tmux supports creating sessions, and with the `-A` flag attaching to session if they already exist rather than creating them. But, if they don't exist and tmux has to create them, what's the best way to supply the information needed to initialize them while retaining the ability to simply attach if a session by the same name already exists.

Answer (score 2):

The `-A` flag takes a command argument that only runs if the session is not initialized,

```
tmux new-session -A -s com "irssi"
```

For example that will either

- Attach to a session named `com`
- Create a session called `com` and start up `irssi` in that session.